google apps gmail addon contextualTrigger is not being called
We are developing a gmail addon to set signatures as soon as compose button in the gmail ui is clicked. Our understanding is that it should call the contextualTriggers, but that doesnt seem to be happening. Tried both with gmail at the root level in the json, and within "addOns"."gmail"
part of appsettings.json
  "gmail": {
    "contextualTriggers": [
      {
        "unconditional": {},
        "onTriggerFunction": "insertQuoteAction"
      }
    ],

Any suggestion?

Hi! I understand that you are trying to include a signature when the Compose Message is triggered. Can you share with me if this Compose Message button you are referring is the one pre built on Gmail or the one Created on your Add on,  Can you also share if you are building the cards you are using for this Apps Script function you are running when triggered.

Yes babanana, the compose msg button is the pre-built one of gmail. I do not want any other button to be clicked (with that the siganture gets added via the composeTrigger.selectActions.runFunction. Requirement is for the signature to get added without any other button click, which is why i was trying to use   contextualTriggers. With the runFunction, am calling another function which builds a card and shows it in the gmail compose menu and which can be clicked.
